# How to access static resources in jar (that correspond to src/main/resources folder)?

Tags: scala, maven, spark-streaming

I have a [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/streaming/) application built with Maven (as jar) and deployed with the `spark-submit` script. The application project layout follows the standard directory layout:

```
myApp
    src
        main
            scala
                com.mycompany.package
                      MyApp.scala
                      DoSomething.scala
                      ...
            resources
                aPerlScript.pl
                 ...
        test
           scala
                com.mycompany.package
                      MyAppTest.scala
                      ...
        target
           ...
pom.xml
```

In the `DoSomething.scala` object I have a method (let's call it `doSomething()`) that tries to execute a Perl script -- `aPerlScript.pl` (from the `resources` folder) -- using `scala.sys.process.Process` and passing two arguments to the script (the first one is the absolute path to a binary file used as input, the second one is the path/name of the produced output file). I call then `DoSomething.doSomething()`.

The issue is that I was not able to access the script, not with absolute paths, relative paths, getClass.getClassLoader.getResource, getClass.getResource, I have specified the resources folder in my `pom.xml`. None of my attempts succeeded. I don't know how to find the stuff I put in src/main/resources.

I will appreciate any help.

**SIDE NOTES:**

- I use an external Process instead of a Spark pipe because, at this step of my workflow, I must handle binary files as input and output.
- I'm using Spark-streaming 1.1.0, Scala 2.10.4 and Java 7. I build the jar with "Maven install" from within Eclipse (Kepler)
- When I use the `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource` "standard" method to access resources I find that the actual classpath is the `spark-submit` script's one.

Comment: Can you `gist.github.com` the code that accesses static resources in Scala? It appears your question is in no way related to Spark itself, but rather a general question about how to access static resources on classpath in Scala. Please help me to understand how much I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions. The simplest is to use Scala's process infrastructure:

```
import scala.sys.process._

object RunScript {
  val arg = "some argument"
  val stream = RunScript.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("aPerlScript.pl")
  val ret: Int = (s"/usr/bin/perl - $arg" #< stream).!
}
```

In this case, `ret` is the return code for the process and any output from the process is directed to `stdout`.

A second (longer) solution is to copy the file `aPerlScript.pl` from the jar file to some temporary location and execute it from there. This code snippet should have most of what you need.

```
object RunScript {
  // Set up copy destination from the Java temporary directory. This is /tmp on Linux
  val destDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/"
  // Get a stream to the script in the resources dir
  val source = Channels.newChannel(RunScript.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("aPerlScript.pl"))
  val fileOut = new File(destDir, "aPerlScript.pl")
  val dest = new FileOutputStream(fileOut)
  // Copy file to temporary directory
  dest.getChannel.transferFrom(source, 0, Long.MaxValue)
  source.close()
  dest.close()
}
// Schedule the file for deletion for when the JVM quits
sys.addShutdownHook {
  new File(destDir, "aPerlScript.pl").delete
}
// Now you can execute the script.
```

This approach allows you to bundle native libraries in JAR files. Copying them out allows the libraries to be loaded at runtime for whatever JNI mischief you have planned.

Comment: Hi @david-weber, thanks for your answer.

This solution might be an option that, actually, works. Just to be precise, in my case I had to declare also the resources path, i.e.:

   `val source = Channels.newChannel(LibLoader.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/aPerlScript.pl"))`

Comment: I've up-voted your answer, but for the moment I decided not to mark it as accepted one, since I'd still need a way to run _aPerlScript.pl_ without the needing of copying it to a local dir first. BTW, thank you very much.

Comment: Quite long, actually. And my spark streaming application needs to call it for every input item!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62568/discussion-between-david-weber-and-erond).

Comment: The **first solution** actually do **works**, even if in this case as well I had to add the complete (relative) path to the script, i.e. `"resou‌​rces/aPerlScript.pl"`. However, as mentioned in chat, my issue has not been completely solved yet: I still need to pass 2 values as arguments to the script (in particular, the first one is the absolute path of an input binary file and the second one is the path/name the processed output will have once saved as a local file). Is there a way a can do this using the first short (cool) solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: This one is too easy. See the fix.

Comment: And David hit one outta the ballpark! **IT WORKS**! Thank you VERY much, I've just accepted the answer.

Comment: Hey David, do you mind to give me a little help again? My requirements are changed now, and I need to feed the perl script with both 1 argument (a string) and the content of a binary file on stdin. For this last reason, I'm unable to pass the perl code as a stream. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest writing the binary file to a temporary location and passing the path to the file on the command line.