# execute a script contained within a resource bundle in a jar

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a script that is added to the resources section of the project.

When testing all works as expected but when the project is compiled to a jar the resource isn't available anymore as a "loose" file. But instead in the jar itself.

How can I still use that script in that case?

in development running the script like this:

```
val script: String = getClass.getResource("/scripts/myScript.py").getPath
...
s"python $script $flags"!
```

Comment: Anything prevents you from extracting it to a temporary file and running python against that file?

Comment: Have you considered using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204566/706557

Answer (score 1):

Use with *[Jython](http://www.jython.org/)* as follows:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

val pyEngine = new ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("python")
val script = new InputStreamReader(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/scripts/myScript.py"))
pyEngine.eval(script)
```

See also [information about installing the latest release of *Jython*](http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.com/2017/07/jython-271-final-released.html).

Comment: But the script is a Python script. Did you mean that you don't want to use Jython?

Comment: i just gave an example. It could be a ruby script or a shell script or any arbitrary resource,.

Comment: I answered the question you posed. But the ScriptEngine approach works for a variety of script types.